# Regex, how to find a file in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have two Ruby files:

```
db/migrate/20120920180336_create_admin_pages.rb
db/migrate/20120920150716_devise_create_users.rb
```

There's a constant variable in this file: `_create_admin_pages.rb`

How can I find it in a file and make the following command work right?

```
gsub_file "db/migrate/*_create_admin_pages.rb", "t.boolean :published", "t.boolean :published, :default => false"
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use Ruby to do this?

Comment: I use it in generator. Probably you can tell me better solution.

Comment: You need to show the code you've written trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Create new app and run $> rake rails:template LOCATION=https://raw.github.com/gist/3757967/47f120271480a531faac74f50a3f96d3cf1e0606/pages.rb     (Try that 2d line in the file do work and change your migration file as I described)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ruby -pe 'gsub("t.boolean :published", "t.boolean :published, :default => false")' < db/migrate/*_create_admin_pages.rb
```

Ruby can run with several options. Here the `-pe` option (actually two options) let Ruby execute this loop:

- Until no more input:
- read a line of input,
- run the string after `-pe` as code,
- print the result.

All using the implicit variable `$_`, the last read line.

Comment: You might want to explain what `-pe` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
gsub_file Dir['db/migrate/*_create_admin_pages.rb'].first, "t.boolean :published", "t.boolean :published, :default => false"
```